# Can not change external Ubuntu to UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair

I have Ubuntu installed in an external device (GPT) in Legacy mode. I could run this Ubuntu in my old Windows 7 laptop. Now I have changed to a Windows 10 laptop in UEFI mode and I can't run ubuntu unless I enable Legacy mode.

So my problem is that I want to [change Ubuntu to UEFI mode without reinstalling](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_mode). When I run Boot-Repair, a message pops up saying:

> The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session.

But I can't open Ubuntu if the legacy mode is disabled!

Is there any solution?

### Edit: Solution

1. Create a [EFI partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition)
2. As Melebius pointed out, Install [Boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) in a flash usb
3. Boot the flash usb in UEFI mode and follow the instructions.

Comment: Do you run Boot-Repair using a live medium or from your main Ubuntu installation?

Comment: From main Installation. I have tried also from a second ubuntu installation (not live session) as posted in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067056/can-i-run-an-actual-installed-ubuntu-as-a-live-session

Comment: UEFI's default is gpt partitioning. Did you use gpt on external drive. Most legacy installs are BIOS/MBR. You can convert drive in place from MBR to gpt but may be able to boot using MBR with UEFI. But will need an ESP - efi system partition. Not sure how to create with MBR but it must be FAT32 with boot flag. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html But external drives only boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. I typically copy /EFI/ubuntu twice to external and second copy is to /EFI/Boot and then I rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you should run Boot-Repair in UEFI mode. Since your main installation does not support that, you have to get a system where it’s possible. Moreover, modifying important properties of the running installations (like moving the root partition) is mostly not possible.

The easiest way is to run Boot-Repair from [Ubuntu live medium](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) or even using the [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/). Make sure to boot it in UEFI mode, the particular procedure depends on your hardware (or *firmware* to be precise).